# Tensorflow weighted vs sigmoid cross-entropy loss

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, multilabel-classification, cross-entropy

I am trying to implement multi-label classification using TensorFlow (i.e., each output pattern can have many active units). The problem has imbalanced classes (i.e., much more zeros than ones in the labels distribution, which makes label patterns very sparse).

The best way to tackle the problem should be to use the `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` function. However, I get this runtime error:

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype uint8 for Tensor with dtype float32
```

I can't understand what is wrong here. As input to the loss function, I pass the labels tensor, the logits tensor, and the positive class weight, which is a constant:

```
positive_class_weight = 10
loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(targets=labels, logits=logits, pos_weight=positive_class_weight)
```

Any hints about how to solve this? If I just pass the same labels and logits tensors to the `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy` loss function, everything works well (in the sense that Tensorflow runs properly, but of course following training predictions are always zero).

See related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697216/multilabel-image-classification-with-sparse-labels-in-tensorflow/47834138#47834138).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is likely to be thrown after the loss function, because the only significant difference between `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy` and `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` is the shape of the *returned tensor*.

Take a look at this example:

```py
logits = tf.linspace(-3., 5., 10)
labels = tf.fill([10,], 1.)

positive_class_weight = 10
weighted_loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(targets=labels, logits=logits, pos_weight=positive_class_weight)
print(weighted_loss.shape)

sigmoid_loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=labels, logits=logits)
print(sigmoid_loss.shape)
```

Tensors `logits` and `labels` are kind of artificial and both have shape `(10,)`. But it's important that `weighted_loss` and `sigmoid_loss` are different. Here's the output:

```py
(10,)
()
```

This is because `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy` performs reduction (the sum by default). So in order to replicate it, you have to wrap the weighted loss with `tf.reduce_sum(...)`.

If this doesn't help, make sure that `labels` tensor has type `float32`. This bug is very easy to make, e.g., the following declaration won't work:

```py
labels = tf.fill([10,], 1)  # the type is not float!
```

You might be also interested to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995).

Comment: Thanks so much, this solved the problem. I had to both explicitly cast the labels into `float32`, and to reduce the loss output using `tf.reduce_sum(...)`.