# How to apply a loss metric that will penalize predicting all zeros in multilabel classification problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Say I have a classification problem that has 30 potential binary labels. These labels are not mutually exclusive. The labels tend to be sparse--there is, on average, 1 positive label per all 30 labels but sometimes more than only 1. In the following code, how can I penalize the model from predicting all zeros? The accuracy will be high, but recall will be awful!

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


OUTPUT_NODES = 30
np.random.seed(0)


def get_dataset():
    """
    Get a dataset of X and y. This is a learnable problem as there is some signal in the features. 10% of the time, a
    positive-output's index will also have a positive feature for that index
    :return: X and y data for training
    """
    n_observations = 30000
    y = np.random.rand(n_observations, OUTPUT_NODES)
    y = (y <= (1 / OUTPUT_NODES)).astype(int)  # Makes a sparse output where there is roughly 1 positive label: ((1 / OUTPUT_NODES) * OUTPUT_NODES ≈ 1)

    X = np.zeros((n_observations, OUTPUT_NODES))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j, feature in enumerate(y[i]):
            if feature == 1:
                X[i][j] = 1 if np.random.rand(1) > 0.9 else 0  # Makes the input features more noisy
                # X[i][j] = 1  # Using this instead will make the model perform very well

    return X, y


def create_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=(OUTPUT_NODES, ))
    dense1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(input_layer)
    dense2 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(dense1)
    output_layer = Dense(30, activation='sigmoid')(dense2)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['Recall'])

    return model


def main():
    X, y = get_dataset()
    model = create_model()
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)

    X_pred = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, OUTPUT_NODES))
    y_pred = model.predict(X_pred)

    print(X_pred)
    print(y_pred.round(1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I believe I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47786650/11002611) that I could use:

```
weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits
```

to address this issue. How would that affect my final output layer's activation functions? Would I have to have an activation function? How do I specify a penalty to misclassifications of a true positive class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it is an interesting problem
First you need to define a weighted cross entropy loss wrapper:

```
def wce_logits(positive_class_weight=1.):
  def mylossw(y_true, logits):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.float32), pos_weight=positive_class_weight))
    return cross_entropy
  return mylossw
```

The *positive_class_weight* is applied to the positive class data. You need this wrapper for *tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits* to get a loss function that takes y_true and y_pred (only) as inputs.
Note that you must cast y_true to float32.

Second, you can not use the predefined Recall, because it does not work with logits. I found a workaround [in this discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42182)

```
class Recall(tf.keras.metrics.Recall):
    def __init__(self, from_logits=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._from_logits = from_logits

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        if self._from_logits:
            super(Recall, self).update_state(y_true, tf.nn.sigmoid(y_pred), sample_weight)
        else:
            super(Recall, self).update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```

Finally, you need to remove the sigmoid activation from the last layer as you are using logits

```
def create_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=(OUTPUT_NODES, ))
    dense1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(input_layer)
    dense2 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(dense1)
    output_layer = Dense(30)(dense2)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=wce_logits(positive_class_weight=27.), metrics=[Recall(from_logits=True)])

    return model
```

Note that the positive weight is set to 27 here. You can read [a discussion on how to correctly calculate the weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564490/how-correctly-calculate-tf-nn-weighted-cross-entropy-with-logits-pos-weight-vari)

Comment: Great response. These methods you provided work and do produce the desired result. This has made the model have a tendency to predict more 1's instead of all zeros

Comment: This problem is also interesting because you can then get the model to predict all 1's by making the positive_class_weight parameter a very large number (like 1000).